# android Zoom and location of a point with current zoom in a view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, zooming, pinchzoom

I am having a view. In which i have set a background image

```
 @Override
public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d) {
    super.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
}
```

On top of this image i am having various number of points and on those points i have drawn cicles using canvas ondraw method .

Now i want to add zoom functionality on the background image and also find the respective points so that the circles remain on same location.

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView
I tried this but don't kw how can i cannot figure out how to zoom my background image that i am placing from above method and also can't get the respective drawn points location.

Comment: Can't you use simple `ZoomControls`? If already tried, what's the problem?